# Firebase google authentication not working android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I migrated my old google sign into firebase authentication. google login properly for old version supporting google, but for firebase auth, I am getting `DEVELOPER_ERROR`.

I also tried adding a `SHA-1` key to the firebase console, but I'm getting this error:

```
An OAuth2 client already exists for this package name and SHA-1 in another project.
You can omit the SHA-1 for now and read more about this situation and how to resolve it
```

Again the possible solution for this is to whitelist the client id. I [followed this guide](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008?authuser=0) but it won't helped me,I'm still getting `DEVELOPER_ERROR`.

Comment: Find and delete your old/other project on Google developer console / Firebase console. Delete only if you are not using anymore. I faced similar case, and i deleted unused project which got conflicts key on google developer console. then it working fine.

Comment: @james how to find due to which project I am getting a conflict?

Comment: since you migrated from google api based into firebase, so i think you can remove your project from google console.  "how to find due to which project I am getting a conflict?" for this case, find with your package id.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two projects of same package name. Even if you delete it. It will take at least 4-5 days to get deleted fully from developer's console.

So one solution is  generate a new SHA-1 key by custom signing the app by generating a signed apk from android studio. Or just create a new project with different package name both ways will work for now.

Hope this info helps. Do let me know if it changes anything for you.
I encourage you to go through these official Google docs on signing apk [1](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually) to understand this process.

Comment: I tried with new sign certificate it wasn't helped me , existing Google stopped working and play store won't allow to  auto update the app.i don't to loose my existing user.changing package name it also not solution for me

Answer (score 1):

The error says itself that you already have a project in google console. As you were using old google login, your project and auth key was created for that package name in google console. Delete the newly created project from firebase and then while adding click on import project from google console. This will import your project from google console and add it to firebase with the old auth key and sha-1. Download google-json and follow the guidelines to set up the project. Then only you will be able to login using firebase.

Comment: Are you able to login now?

Comment: good to know. Accept the answer and up vote it so it can be helpful to other users too.

Comment: I mean already I am imported my existing project, but not working login